# Construct tensors from differential forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, tensors

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, differential forms are defined using tensors, could we define a tensor using a differential form? For example, if $\omega$ is a two-form on $M$ which is expressed locally as
$$F(p)=F_{ij}(p)e^i\wedge e^j,$$
where $e_i$ is an o.n. basis for $T_pM$ and $F_{ji}=-F_{ij}$, is $T=(F_{ij}-F_{ji})e^i\otimes e^j$ a well-defined two-tensor on $M$?

Added: is $F(p)=\sigma_{ij}F_{ij}(p)e^i\wedge e^j$ well-defined? where $\sigma_{ij}=1$ or $-1$.

Edited according to Hurkyl's answer.

Comment: you can define some tensors, but, not all. For example, I think that $e^1 \otimes e^1$ is impossible to produce unless your going to cheat and use contractions. In which case, the question is silly. In any event, Hurkyl's answer is nice so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I am confused with compatability with local coordinates, i.e., it is invariant under coordinate change. For example, if $$F_{12}e^1\wedge e^2+F_{13}e^1\wedge e^3+F_{45}e^4\wedge e^5$$ is globally defined, is $F_{12}e^1\wedge e^2-F_{13}e^1\wedge e^3+F_{45}e^4\wedge e^5$ or $F_{12}e^1\wedge e^2+F_{13}e^1\wedge e^3-F_{45}e^4\wedge e^5$ also globally defined?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook in what way is using contractions cheating?  This is a Riemannian manifold.

Comment: @Muphrid I would think with a contraction you could get back to the basis hence trivially write any tensor in terms of contracted forms. Of course, contractions are not generally cheating... they're necessary and interesting!

Answer (score 6):

Nope! For example, $e^1 \wedge e^2$ and $-(e^2 \wedge e^1)$ are the same 2-form, however $e^1 \otimes e^2$ and $-(e^2 \otimes e^1)$ are quite different tensors.

However, this can be repaired, as the map $x \wedge y \mapsto \frac{1}{2} (x \otimes y - y \otimes x)$ *does* induces a homomorphism from 2-forms to tensors. Furthermore, this map splits the projection map induced by $x \otimes y \mapsto x \wedge y$. (i.e. doing the former then the latter gives you the 2-form you started with)

(alternatively, you could insist on $F_{ij}$ being anti-symmetric)

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited the tensor $T$ according to your answer, is the new $T$ well-defined?

Comment: So is there any difference other than forms are antisymmetric and alternating and general tensors are not?

Comment: I guess no other difference.

Comment: what I am not sure is compatibility.

Comment: If you're asking the *precise* thing I think you're asking, then that is the only difference: the tensor product is the "universal" way to construct a product of vectors, and the wedge product of vectors of the same type is the "universal" way to construct an alternating product of vectors. The fact you can embed the space of wedge products is an additional "surprise" beyond this universal property, which is sometimes taken too far: sometimes people won't even introduce the space of wedge products, and instead say that forms *are* the antisymmetric tensors.

Comment: The example I am thinking is vector fields on $S^2$, any vector field on $S^2$ must vanish somewhere. For tensors, do we have the same phonomenon? For example is $T=(1+x_i^2+x_j^2)dx^i\otimes dx^j$ well-defined on $S^4$?